# Android studio Bumblebee build.gradle root project can't add classpath dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, groovy, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to implement dagger-hilt in my new project but I see some differences in the new Android studio version (Bumblebee 2021.1.1):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
        hilt_version = '2.40.5'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'
}    

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I try to implement hilt and the dependency block with classpath it tells me:

```
 Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
        }
```

Comment: Did you get it working with the plugin way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add plugins in the Android Studio Bumblebee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650972/how-to-add-plugins-in-the-android-studio-bumblebee)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Resolved by adding the depencies{} block into the buildScript block :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
        hilt_version = '2.40.5'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false

}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved dependencies issues in new android studio on app level **.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolve dependencies issue on project level include build script above plugins block**

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```