# Android studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 gradle files

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-hilt, android-studio-bumblebee

I updated to  Android studio Bumblebee  2021.1.1 ,
the gradle.settings(Project) file structure changes,
How can I add the dependencies and classpath for hilt or navigation now?

[image: Android Studio gradle]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add plugins in the Android Studio Bumblebee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650972/how-to-add-plugins-in-the-android-studio-bumblebee)

Answer (score 4):

You can use dependencies as below in Project level bulild.gradle

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false

id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

Comment: and how i can add navigation plugin classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.1")  ?

Comment: Updated for navigation as well @RohitJakhar

Answer (score 3):

You can add it at the first line

[image: You can add it at the first line]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Add **Project level dependencies** inside **buildscript block** like shown below :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha04'
        hilt_version = '2.41'
        accompanist_version = '0.24.2-alpha'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.5'\
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0-alpha03' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0-alpha03' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is necessary to live like writing an add-on to be added, for this I am showing such an example.

the code is id
'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version'2.4.2' apply false
you need to write like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Add this two lines in Project level build gradle

```
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false

id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.4.2' apply false
```

Add in App level build gradle

```
plugins {
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin' 
}
```